# be careful that-clause and be careful wh-clause

Tags: adjectives, complements, wh-questions

> 1. I'll be more careful what I say in the future.
> 2. We were very careful that he didn't find out.

The that-clause in sentence 2 is a complement of the adjective careful. The wh-clause in sentence 1 seems to be a noun phrase, rather than an embedded question, which I'm not sure of. Either way, I think the wh-clause serves a similar purpose as the th-clause does.

My question is, why is there no preposition governing the wh-clause?